# How to solved UIManager['AIRMapLite'] is no longer supported. (White Screen with white Logo)

Tags: react-native, android-mapview

I'm not able to solve this problem for the last 2 days. I've done the search and read documents of mapview but still unable to solve it.

[image: Error]

I will show you my codes and the scenario that I do.

**My Import**

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
```

**My Function**

```
    export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          zoomEnabled = {true}
          style={ styles.map }
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Lastly the activation key of google

```
<meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="i make it secret first"
      />
```

[image: Activate]

this is the error in my console, I don't know the issue happen

```
    if (__DEV__) {
  Object.keys(UIManager).forEach(viewManagerName => {
    if (!UIManagerProperties.includes(viewManagerName)) {
      if (!viewManagerConfigs[viewManagerName]) {
        viewManagerConfigs[viewManagerName] = UIManager[viewManagerName];
      }
      defineLazyObjectProperty(UIManager, viewManagerName, {
        get: () => {
          console.warn(
            `Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager via UIManager['${viewManagerName}'] ` +
              `is no longer supported. Use UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('${viewManagerName}') instead.`,
          );
          return UIManager.getViewManagerConfig(viewManagerName);
        },
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Share line 163 of UIManager.js

Comment: see the update bro

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a known issue in `react-native-maps`. An [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2620) was initially created in December 2018.

It is actually an issue with how the dependency has been implemented. So there isn't really anything that you can do about it other than forking the repo, and fixing the underlying issue yourself.

As of the 11 March 2019, it has now been fixed and should no longer be an issue. The fix has been included in the next release. So once the next release of `react-native-maps` is out you should no longer experience the warning.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2620#issuecomment-471650689

> fixed on master, should be included in the next release

If you cannot wait for the issue to be fixed and you want to hide the [YellowBox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#warnings) warning you can do it by using the following

```
import {YellowBox} from 'react-native';
```

Then inside your render method, I usually do it in the `App.js` so it is easy to keep track of which ones I have hidden.

```
render() {
  YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: ...']);  // <- insert the warning text here you wish to hide. 
  return (
    //cool ui stuff
  );
}
```

It won't remove the warning from your console, but it will remove any YellowBox warnings associated with the error.

Comment: You can use it. It's just a warning. Once the new version is released, update, and the warning will go. You shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: last thing where should i put the YellowBox ignore?

Comment: I usually put it as the first thing in my render of my `App.js`

Comment: You need to put the correct text in the array. I imagine the text you need to put in should be something like `'Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager view UiManager[AirMapLite] is no longer supported.'`

Comment: the error shows. i already import YellowBox and I add this after import YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager view UiManager[AirMapLite] is no longer supported.']);

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem on my machine. It is hiding the the YellowBox warning on the device. But as I said in my answer it **WILL NOT** remove it from the console. You will always see it in the console.

Comment: ah i see thank you, still the map is not showing, it shows brown map and logo of google

Comment: That is a different problem, so you should post a new question.